# The type or namespace name 'function' could not be found?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am writing a function proc in my C# 2008 ASP.Net application and I get the following error:

> The type or namespace name 'function'
>   could not be found (are you missing a
>   using directive or an assembly
>   reference) ?

Any idea what this means?

Comment: Can you post the code in question?

Comment: // This is all the code I have
private function ValidateData()
{

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, you have written something like this:

```
private function ValidateData() {}
```

If that is correct, then you need to change it to something like this:

```
private bool ValidateData() {}
```

where `bool` in this example, is your return type (boolean).  If you have no return (then it is not a function).  Here is what you would do then:

```
private void ValidateData() {}
```

Comment: ok, for my own information purposes, why is the word "string" (return type) required?

Comment: Its not required.  If there is no return, then use `void`

Comment: ok, but something is required (either a return type or a void keyword), correct?

Comment: No problem.  Check out my blog at http://www.thecodepage.com - periodically, I will have tips that may be useful.

Answer (score 2):

"function" is a JavaScript keyword, not a C# keyword. Maybe the compiler thinks your JavaScript is meant to be C#.

Answer (score 1):

```
private function ValidateData() { }
```

you need to replace "function" with the return type of the function. In this case it would be void meaning that there is no return value.

```
private void ValidateData() { }
```